# Store and display input message in formArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have created an input field where the user can enter a message and on keyup enter I want to display this message.

```
export class AppComponent  {
 
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }


  onEnter() {
    this.addThing();
  }

  get things() {
    return this.myForm.get('things') as FormArray;
  }

  private createForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      things: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control('')
      ])
    });
  }

  private addThing() {
    this.things.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="display-text">
                            <p
                               *ngFor="let thing of things.controls; let i=index">{{thing.value}}
                            >
                                {{ message.value | json}}
                            </p>
                        </div>
<div class="input">
                <form [formGroup]="myForm">
                    <ng-container formArrayName="things">
                        <ng-container
                            ngFor="let thing of things.controls; let i = index "
                        >
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                (keyup.enter)="onEnter()"
                            />
                        </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
                </form>
            </div>
```

When pressing enter, the message is not displayed in the window. Can someone help?

The Problem seems to be that no value is being stored in the formArray

[image]

Comment: `this.fb.control()` creates a new `FormControl` object which you then add to your array. There is no value bound to it hence there is nothing to display. You'll want to bind your input to something and then use that value.

Comment: Yes this is what I want. So you mean the addThing() function is incorrectly implemented?

Comment: Indeed. You want to add the input value inside the new `FormControl` object, ie `this.fb.control('new value')`.

Comment: Do I have to change the method to this:  private addThing(control: AbstractControl) {
    this.things.push(this.fb.control(control));
  }

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzmqk9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html can you provide here your recommendation on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you actually needing a formgroup here, I would just use a formcontrol for the input and a formarray or even just a "regular" JS array, I would probably use just that, but here is anyway sample of usage of formarray:

TS:

```ts
myInput = this.fb.control('');
things = this.fb.array([]);

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

addThing() {
  this.things.push(this.fb.control(this.myInput.value)); // push value to formarray
  this.myInput.reset(); // reset input field
}
```

and template:

```html
<input [formControl]="myInput" (keyup.enter)="addThing()" />

<p *ngFor="let thing of things.controls">
  {{ thing.value }}
</p>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-inqa81?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your solution a bit.

```html
<div class="display-text">
  <p *ngFor="let thing of things.controls;">
    {{ thing.value }}
  </p>
</div>

<div class="input" [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="inputValue" (keyup.enter)="addThing()" />
</div>
```

and the TS code

```js
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  get things() {
    return this.myForm.get('things') as FormArray;
  }

  private createForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      inputValue: this.fb.control(''),
      things: this.fb.array([this.fb.control('')]),
    });
  }

  private addThing() {
    this.things.push(this.fb.control(this.myForm.get('inputValue').value));
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q6nvn3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)